# Pass Implementation to Angular Module When importing it

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

If I have an Angular Module `A` that depends on a certain service `S`. But instead of implementing the service directly, I want to deal with an interface `I` and let the consumer of `A` pass the actual implementation when importing it. The implementation will be an Angular service decorated with @Injectable and has its own dependencies.

Is that feasible in Angular? if yes, what are the steps to implement it?

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#ngmodule-providers, you can specify which value to provide

Comment: I have already checked the guide. I am not providing a value! I need to provide a service that has its own set of dependencies. Please read the question, and ask for clarifications if needed.

Comment: Why the downvote? I think this a good question. Maybe you could add any sort of research/implementation efforts that you have done until now, OP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To archive this, you could use `abstract classes` instead of `interfaces` to make the implementations exchangeable:

```
app/
├── foo.service.ts
├── foo/
│   ├── abstract-foo.provider.ts
│   ├── foo.module.ts
│   ├── foo.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
```

Now the following files:

```
// foo.service.ts
@Injectable()
export class FooService extends AbstractFooProvider {
   ctor(private _fooDependency: SomeOtherFooService){}
   foo(): boolean {
     return this._fooDependency.isFoo();
   }
}

// foo.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [FooComponent],
  exports: [FooComponent]
})
export class FooModule {
   static withConfiguration(implementationProvider: Provider): ModuleWithProviders {
     return {
        ngModule: FooModule,
        providers: [implementationProvider]
     };
   }
}

// abstract-foo.provider.ts
export abstract class AbstractFooProvider {
    foo(): boolean;
}

// foo.component.ts
@Component({})
export class FooComponent {
   ctor(private _fooProvider: AbstractFooProvider){}
}

// app.module.ts    

export const FOO_PROVIDER : ClassProvider = {
  provide: AbstractFooProvider, 
  useClass: FooService
};

@NgModule({
   imports: [
      FooModule.withConfiguration(FOO_PROVIDER)
   ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use an `InjectionToken`:

```
export let SERVICE_A = new InjectionToken<MyService>('service.a');
```

Here, I've created an injection token for the interface `MyService`.

In my module, I match that token to a given implementation:

```
{ provide: SERVICE_A, useClass: ServiceImplA },
```

Then, in my component I specify which token to use:

```
constructor(@Inject(SERVICE_A) private service: MyService) { }
```

You can, of course, create a different token for each implementation.

---

Here is an example in StackBlitz. To see it in action, you can change the token from `SERVICE_A` to `SERVICE_B`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwglpj?file=app%2Fhello.component.ts0